# Simulate non-standard resolution

Tags: windows-8, resolution, windows-store-apps

I am working on a project that will be targeted to a specific device, and the device has a resolution of 1280 x 800.  I am aware of the restrictions on a Store app that mean limited functional support for this resolution (no snapped view, etc), but I was wondering if there was a way to configure the simulator to work in a non-standard resolution.  Currently all the screens we have developed have been done blind (or at least against a resolution of 1366x768) as we don't have an actual device to build against.  As a result we really don't know how the layouts are going to look on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Change Resolution button on right edge of the simulator.  9th button down, the icon looks like an LCD display.  1200x800 is one of the resolutions provided in the dropdown list.  I'd post a screenshot if I knew how to make one, the simulator works a bit too well for that ;)

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the different resolutions, but for some reason assumed 1280x800 wasn't in the list.